# Silverlight 4: Resolving Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets was not found?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, silverlight

I've been upgrading some Silverlight 3 apps to Silverlight 4 in Visual Studio 2010. My Silverlight 3 apps open fine in Visual Studio, but SL4 apps don't, with the following error:

`C:\Path\To\MyProject.csproj : error  : Unable to read the project file 'XNTVOD.AdminClient.csproj'. 
C:\Path\To\MyProject.csproj(593,3): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.`

I had a problem with older VS Silverlight components and recently uninstalled most of the SL components, and right now in Add/Remove programs I have:

1. Microsoft Silverlight
2. Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK
3. Microsoft Silverlight 4 Toolkit April 2010

The `<import>` declaration looks like this for the SL4 project:

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Silverlight\$(SilverlightVersion)\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets" />`

That folder, `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v4.0` only has two files in it:

`Microsoft.Ria.Client.targets`

`Microsoft.Ria.Client.VisualStudio.targets`

What Silverlight development component am I missing in particular? I see a bunch of different options, from Silverlight 4 SDK Beta to VS Tools for Silverlight 4 and a bunch of others. I don't want to install stuff that will get me right back to the situation I had before this one with outdated components.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. My error is telling me I'm missing the proper file in "\Silverlight\v3.0" even though I have v4.0 installed. I also have the proper Silverlight 4.0 file, but VS doesn't seem to see it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Looks like this is the missing piece...

[Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b3deb194-ca86-4fb6-a716-b67c2604a139)

Comment: What about Visual Studio 2015 ? Is there a distinct link per visual studio version - or is the version indifferent ?

Answer (score 18):

The file that's missing ships in the Silverlight 4 SDK.  You can either install just the [Silverlight 4 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7335), or re-install the entire [Silverlight 4 Tools for VS2010](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=177428) package (which will re-install the developer runtime, SDK, a hotfix for VS2010, the Silverlight 4 Tools package, and WCF RIA Services).

Comment: In case of VS SP1, you can't reistall the SL 4 Tools fo VS2010. Just (re)install the SDK.

Comment: Installing the Silverlight 4 SDK was what I needed, because I needed it available while not having VS2010 but 2013

Answer (score 11):

You may get this with Silverlight version 4 projects when trying to open in version 5 if version 4 bits are not on that machine.  What has worked for me (after several hours of trying everything) is to edit the csproj file and change the silverlight target version

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

From 4 to 5

Comment: This worked great for me! And I didn't have to install any of the 4.0 components that I would have never used. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting this problem, and already ha[d,ve] v5.0 in that section.

Comment: You need to [build it using **x86** instead of **Any CPU**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5925686/175679).

Answer (score 5):

This worked well for me...also had to install [Silverlight 4 Developer runtime](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188039)

Answer (score 4):

Afer many tries, what worked for me was:
1. go to add or remove programms
2. remove all silverlight versions installed (4, 5 or even if version is not specified remove it too!)
3. install Silverlight 4 SDK
4. install Silverlight 5 for developers
Finally opened the project in VS 2010 SP1

Answer (score 0):

A previously working installation can break when you install a new version of TFS on the server (or whatever it was that messed with my MSBuild).

My 'targets' files had disappeared from `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v5.0` on Server 2012 and reinstalling the tools.

I believe it may be possible to just copy the targets files from another machine but not 100% sure.