# Project unavailable if Solution Contain Multiple Projects. [VS2010]

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I am downloading **sample projects** from various websites.

And if it contain **multiple project** in One **solution**.

And when i clicking on the main solution file……it opens only one main projects other projects **remain unavailable** though it is present in folders…with their project files………

and though i am trying to add manually each project in Solution though it gives me errore
see image of error message also....

**NOTE:** i am using VS2010 and i am trying to load SilverLight Projects

See below image
[image]

**error when manually adding project in solution**
[image]

Comment: Are the .csProj files present?

Comment: ya .csproj file are present.......see i have update question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link will help you

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/54197/386127.aspx#386127

It seems maybe SDK is not installed or badly installed..

Comment: i have changed  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Silverlight\$(SilverlightVersion)\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets" /> to <Import Project="C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v3.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets" />  still getting error===> Build Does not Exist?

Comment: Are you using silverlight4? try maybe this http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b3deb194-ca86-4fb6-a716-b67c2604a139

Comment: as seen here in fact  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591369/silverlight-4-resolving-microsoft-silverlight-csharp-targets-was-not-found