# Unable to load Silverlight 3 Project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I've been trying to open a Silverlight 3 solution in Visual Studio 2010, but I've been getting the following error:

> Unable to read the project file 'ESM.Visualization.csproj'. C:\Code\ESM\ESM.Visualization\ESM.Visualization.csproj(238,3): The imported project "C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v3.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on the disk.

I found that I didn't have Silverlight v3.0 but I couldn't find a way to get Silverlight 3.0 on my Visual Studio 2010, especially since I have Silverlight v4.0 already installed.

Comment: Also [resolving-microsoft-silverlight-csharp-targets-was-not-found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591369/silverlight-4-resolving-microsoft-silverlight-csharp-targets-was-not-found) is a useful link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must change your *.csproj file manually.

Open it in any text editor, navigate to the line with the incorrect code (number 238, I suppose) and check that it looks so:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Silverlight\$(SilverlightVersion)\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets" />
```

Then change these lines, set the content of the second element to "v4.0":

```
<TargetFrameworkIdentifier>Silverlight</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<SilverlightVersion>$(TargetFrameworkVersion)</SilverlightVersion>
```

Comment: Will that have any adverse effects on the project? I was thinking about doing that, but I didn't want to accidentally break all the things.

Comment: @Yawus, it will work the same if you edit the project settings by using the visual studio editor (select another version of Sivlerlight from the combobox). There is no magic: the default editor just changes the *.csproj file, nothing more. So you can do the same thing manually.